# Toggle Slide and Hide

Tags: jquery

Searhed a bit and couldn't find it.

I'm sitting with a issue here.
on http://cmctest.netserver11.net, i have 6 images wich has a toggle jquery function.
Problem is, that when i, toggle twice, the other one dissapears.
I tried the jquery hide function but it was regardless.

Only thing i need for this is, when you toggle the second, the first one will collapse.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
    {
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Would be awesome if you could help!
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to hide all before slide down

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide(); // hide all

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading img").click(function()
    {
        jQuery(".content").slideUp(500); // slide all up
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

There is no need to use `slideToggle()` for what you want to acomplish, don't "ask" the user to click again to hide the text...

by the way... you should use a `<ul>` instead a bunch of `<div>`'s for your markup, something like:

```
<ul id="content">
    <li class="item">
       <img src="/images/minified/closedcolored.png" alt="" />
       <div class="description">
          <h2>Acquisitie</h2>
          <p>Hoe scherp bent u als het gaat om het werven en houden van klanten?</p>
       </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

then you can easily do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".description").hide(); // hide all

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".item img").click(function()
    {
        jQuery(".description").slideUp(500); // slide all up
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

I just **forgot** one little detail!

inside the click method, replace what you have with:

```
jQuery(".description").slideUp(500); // slide all up
if(!jQuery(this).next().is(":visible")) // is visible already?
    jQuery(this).next().slideDown(500); // slide down
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can set as **correct answer** by clicking the "check" icon on the top left of the answer, and when you find any questions n the forum that you would make yourself, **upvote**, as well for the answers if they have worked for you.

Comment: Thanx for the extra detail, makes it a little smoother. Thank you sir!